# Is there a simple way to loop over all used cells in a workbook in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm incredibly new to VBA, and drafted out a bit of code to replace some portions of hyperlinks. It works great, but now I can't seem to figure out how to make it run over the whole workbook. Here's what I've got:

```
    For Each cell In Range("C13")
        If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            If InStr(cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address, original) <> 0 Then
                temp = final & Mid(cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address, Len(original) + 1)
                cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address = temp
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Right now I just used `range("C13")` as a test, but ideally it would say something like application.workbooks(1) (but of course that doesn't work). Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: We are not seeing the whole procedure. I not sure if I am being able to follow you, but I think you can declare a variable of type range and set it just before the for...next loop and  use it where you have ``Range("C13")``.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each cell In ws.UsedRange

            (your code)

        Next cell
    Next ws
Next wb
```

Working for me using `cell.Value = cell.Value + 1` with multiple workbooks/sheets as a simple test.

Comment: My bad! I hadn't read the question properly. Have corrected above.

Comment: Edited for all open workbooks

Comment: Ahh I see. So you really do have to loop an object only over the next biggest object, you can't just jump straight from a cell to a workbook or a file folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are after code to look at the [hyperlinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.hyperlinks) in a workbook

```
Dim hLink As Hyperlink
Dim iSh As Worksheet

For Each iSh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each hLink In iSh.Hyperlinks

        ' Your code adapted a little bit
        If InStr(hLink.Address, original) <> 0 Then
            temp = Final & Mid(hLink.Address, Len(original) + 1)
            hLink.Address = temp
        End If
        ' End of your code       


    Next
Next
```